# Inverses of Elements in a factor group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Some confusion here.

Let $H\unlhd G$. Consider $xH\in G/H$ where $x\in G$. Does $(xH)^{-1}=x^{-1}H$ necessarily?

I know by normality $xHx^{-1}H = (xx^{-1})H=H$, but I'm not sure if that's strong enough for the above equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly strong enough: You've shown that $(xH) (x^{-1} H) = H$ so in $G/H$, $x^{-1}H$ is the inverse to $x H$ (as $H$ is the identity in $G/H$). Hence, $(xH)^{-1} = x^{-1} H$.